# Stopping waiting threads on condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning multithreading. I am implementing producer and consumer problem. I am stuck on scenario where i want that when I press anything apart from integer from keyboard, all my threads should die and there is no memory in use by threads. Please have your valuable inputs to help me achieve it. Below is all the code I am using.

package com.java.concurrency;

```
    public class ThreadSignaling {
      private int i = -1;
      private boolean valueSet = false;
      private boolean stopFlag = false;

      public void put(int value) {
        synchronized (this) {
          while (valueSet) {
            if (stopFlag) {
              System.out.println("Byeeeeeeeeeeeee");
              break;
            }
            try {
              this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              System.out.println("InterruptedException while waiting in put() : " + e);
            }
          }
          this.i = value;
          this.valueSet = true;
          System.out.println("Value put : " + this.i);
          this.notify();
        }
      }

      public void get() {
        synchronized (this) {
          while (!valueSet) {
            if (stopFlag) {
              System.out.println("Byeeeeeeeeeeeee");
              break;
            }
            try {
              this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              System.out.println("InterruptedException while waiting in get() : " + e);
            }
          }
          System.out.println("Value get : " + this.i);
          valueSet = false;
          this.notify();
        }
      }

      public void finish() {
        synchronized (this) {
          stopFlag = true;
          this.notifyAll();
        }
      }

    }

    public class Producer implements Runnable {
  private ThreadSignaling sharedObj = null;
  private final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public Producer(ThreadSignaling obj) {
    this.sharedObj = obj;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    int value = -1;
    System.out.println("Press Ctrl-c to stop... ");
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Enter any integer value : ");
      if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        value = input.nextInt();
      } else {
        this.sharedObj.finish();
        return;
      }
      this.sharedObj.put(value);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException while sleeping" + e);
      }
    }
  }
}
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
  private ThreadSignaling sharedObj = null;

  public Consumer(ThreadSignaling obj) {
    this.sharedObj = obj;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      this.sharedObj.get();
    }
  }
}
public class MainThread {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadSignaling sharedObj = new ThreadSignaling();
    Producer in = new Producer(sharedObj);
    Consumer out = new Consumer(sharedObj);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(in);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(out);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}    enter code here
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Comment: I am not able to stop all waiting threads on any other input apart from integer

Comment: I was hoping for a little more insight/details into what you were able to find while trying to solve it before you asked here.

Comment: I implemented simple producer Consumer problem. I took user input through producer into in a variable and Consumer consumes it through same variable. what I want is when user give any other input not integer, both consumer and producer threads waiting should be stopped. I am running into infinte loop when try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you do not have an exit condition for the Consumer. The `run()` method of the Consumer will run forever, and while doing repeated `get` calls on the shared object.
What you need to do is to make aware the Consumer that the Producer has set the `stopFlag` in the shared object. And if that `stopFlag` is true then the loop in the Consumer should also finish. There are several ways you can do that:

- redefine `get` method to return the value of stopFlag;
- define a new method to return just the value of stopFlag;

In either cases, make a test in the Consumer.run() and if the value is true, just do a return so the infinite loop ends.